# PIC16F1829: how to read device ID using LVP mode?

Tags: pic, microchip, programming

I am stuck. [Datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/41440a.pdf), [programming guide](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41390C.pdf). LVP mode.

I see how to write to area 0x8000-0x8008 using "load configuration" command, but I do not see how to read this area. It is not a part of the program memory, therefore shifting address from 0 to 0x8000 won't work. There's no command "read configuration". How is programmer supposed to obtain device ID?

I initially used documentation for wrong PIC, where this is easily performed, as well as address is easily managed. With this MCU managing programming seems to be a nightmare.

**Update:** the document programming specifications document is one big mess. If we look at the fig 5.5 it gives a clue that configuration memory can be actually read with the "read program memory" command.

Okay, this seems to help answering my question, **but...**

Another question arises. The description of "load" commands state that these commands load data into the latches and those latches will be written on next "program" command.

1. I do not see a way how to clear these latches - if I issue "load config" command, first latch will be filled with data, an if then I want to revert back to programming main flash, where data from this latch go? Is the only way to get out of LVP mode and get in back?
2. There's a contradiction: 5.0 says

> "The PC’s address at the time the Begin Externally Timed Programming or Begin Internally Timed Programming command is given will determine which location(s) in memory are written"

therefore if I want to prorgam addresses 0x100 to 0x11f, I set address to 0, increment address 256 times, then write to 32 latches incrementing address, then reset address back to 0 and again increment 256 times to 0x100, and issue "program" command? However, the following pic does not list the requirement to roll address back. If there's no requirement, then each latch must be paired with the address it was updated with the data. But then again question - if I load several latches, and changed my mind - how to clear them?

[image]

More here, see picture below: first in the flow is "load configuration", which is expected to fill first latch. Then optional bulk erase, and then "one word program cycle", which assumes writing another, second latch, and issue "program" command. Question - where data from "load configuration" loaded latch goes?

[image]

The whole thing would be manageable if "load configuration" command would just change bit 15 of the address to 1, but it also requires filling the first latch.

**Update:** datasheet has some more information. It confuses even more. Page 107

> It is not necessary to load the entire write latch block with user program data. However, the entire write latch block will be written to program memory.

So what figure 5.3 in the programming guide is about, if datasheet explicitly says it can not write program memory byte-by-byte, but writes entire set of latches (a block) which are counted 32 latches in the PIC16F1829?

**Update:** the stuff was clarified in the Microchip forums and I am now able to big-bang the programming process using GPIO. The documentation is poor and having mistakes and typos and is not appropriate for *successful* programmer design process.